# Finding how many elements are in a string array

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find how many elements are in my string array, so I can add to that array from the first empty element.

Here's what I've tried to do:

```
int arrayLength = 0;
string[] fullName = new string[50];

if (fullName.Length > 0)
{
    arrayLength = fullName.Length - 1;
}
```

and then from that refer to the first available empty element as:

```
fullName[arrayLength] = "Test";
```

I can also use this to see if the array is full or not, but my problem is arrayLength is always equal to 49, so my code seems to be counting the size of the entire array, not the size of the elements that are not empty.

Cheers!

Comment: Why not using a List ?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty", containing `null`?

Comment: (Also, your array length isn't equal to 49, it's equal to 50, with indices from 0 to 49). You shouldn't use the name `arrayLength` to refer to something other than the array length, or you'll come across it later and think that's what it does mean.

Comment: But `string[50]` will always have 50 elements. Consider using `List<string>`

Comment: I'm talking about fullName having, for example, the first 5 elements with a value, and the 45 others being empty. I would like to write code that can find that the 6th element is the first empty element, if that makes sense.

Comment: Well the answer to that starts of as `0` and increases with each addition, so you could just maintain that record. It does seem that you'd be better off with a `List<string>` here though, in a lot of ways. Indeed it seems like you're trying to write your own `List<string>` implementation.

Comment: Array.Length will always return the declared size of the array, i.e. 50 in your case. It doesn't matter whether you have filled a number of the elements because space has already been set aside for you. If you'd like a dynamically sized array of strings, it may be an idea to look at List<string>. If you're stuck with arrays, then you're going to have to iterate through it and compare each item to string.Empty or "".

Comment: I'll have a look into lists. It doesn't have to be perfect, it's just for a small assignment for school. Cheers.

Comment: "how many elements are in array" ..  "add to that array from the first empty element" - the *number* of elements bears **no relation** to the *first empty* element (assuming empty=null)

Comment: If it's an *assignment* then the assignment may be to use an array and if you don't use an array you may fail the assignment.  In this case, I would personally provide an answer with an `array` *and* a vastly more efficient/succinct/etc version with a `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this function to calculate the length of your array.

```
private int countArray(string[] arr)
{
    int res = arr.Length;

    foreach (string item in arr)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
        {
            res -= 1;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

EDIT : To find the first empty element

```
private int firstEmpty(string[] arr)
{
    int res = 0;

    foreach (string item in arr)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
        {
            return res;
        }
        res++;
    }

    return -1; // Array is full
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to find how many elements are in my string array,

```
array.Length
```

> so I can add to that array from the first empty element.

Array's don't have empty elements; there's always something in there, though it could be `null`.

You could find that by scanning through until you hit a null, or by keeping track each time you add a new element.

If you're going to add new elements then, use `List<string>` this has an `Add()` method that will do what you want for you, as well as resizing when needed and so on.

You can likely then just use the list for the next part of the task, but if you really need an array it has a `ToArray()` method which will give you one.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to use the array instead of a list you still simply can get the number of empty elements like this:

```
int numberOfEmptyElements = fullName.Count(x => String.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
    string[] fullName = new string[50];

    fullName[0] = "Rihana";
    fullName[1] = "Ronaldo";

    int result = fullName.Count(i => i != null);
```

in `result` you will have the number of occupied positions. In this case 2, cause 2 arrays are filled. From there you can count the empty. :)